# the variable K reads undefined on my web console even though its fine on my vsc

Tags: javascript

im trying to get the k to work so it will say i will get it on the same day on my vsc code its fine but on my web browser it says the k is undefined.

```
let s=prompt('what will you get?');
if(s===`social`){
     k=prompt(`when?`);
}
else if(s===null || s===``){
    alert(`try again`)
}
else(alert(`try harder`))
if(k===`now`){
    alert(`you will get it on the same day`);
}
//dont forget alert
else if(k===null || k===``){
    alert(alert`keep going`)
}
else(alert`why not`)


let sume= (a,b) => a+b
sume(`3`,`4`)
```

i wanted to see how my function arrow turned out on the web console
until i ran into this error

Answer (score 0):

You have to defind the varible with `var`.

`var k=prompt('when?');`

Since when defining it with `var` it remains as a global variable and not only in the conditional

Comment: thanks so much i thought let and var serve the same purpose

Comment: Your welcome. I share a [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-var-and-let-in-javascript/#:~:text=var%20and%20let%20are%20both,with%20var%20keyword%20are%20hoisted.) where you can know the differences between var and let